# $f(x)=\cos(2x)+5$. Find the points satisfying Rolle's Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Verify that $f(x)=\cos(2x)+5$ satisifes all the conditions of Rolle's theorem in the interval $[0,\pi]$. Find the points satisying the theorem.

So I  have proved that $f(x)$ satisfies the theorem and then:

$f'(c)=-2\sin2c=0$

$$\sin2c=0$$

$$2c=\sin^{-1}(0)$$

$$2c=0,\pi,2\pi$$

so $$c=0,\pi/2,\pi.$$

Is this correct?

Comment: Carefully check Rolle's theorem: it guarantees the existence of such a $c$ in which interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are going to get really persnickety about things (and why not, that is what mathematicians are prone to do) Rolle' theorem says.

If f(a) = f(b) and f is continuous over [a,b] and differentiable over (a,b) then there exists a stationary point in (a,b).

$\pi/2$ is the only stationary point in the open interval.

Comment: Yeah, I was a little confused as the question only had the closed interval but this makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

the answer is only $c=\frac \pi2$ because $c\in (0,\pi)$. So $c\neq 0,\pi$.